# How to switch tabs in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap, and I am trying the first example, where it shows a black bar on top with 3 buttons. So far I have this code.

The example I saw is here
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/starter-template.html

but the tab switching doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <!--
        <input id="test"/>
        <input id="test2"/>
        -->

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Pal</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
            <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

        </div>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">qqq</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="about">ggg</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="contact">jjj</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using bootstrap 2 docs for reference and code files of bootstrap 3? Refer this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
      <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the documentation of the bootstrap, and you have tab pane only and the nav tab are needed to trigger that area,

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs